# how properly deploy WPF app with sqlite database using ClickOnce

Tags: wpf, sqlite, clickonce, publish

I tried to use ClickOnce but database is not included.

When I change database property "build action" to content then it is visible in Publish files properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx

Unfortunately in such case i receive following error:

Error   2   Problem generating manifest. The process cannot access the file 'H:\Repos\InstalmentsManagement\Installments.Wpf\Database\installments.sqlite' because it is being used by another process. Installments.Wpf

My connection string is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="installmentsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/InstallmentsModel.csdl|res://*/InstallmentsModel.ssdl|res://*/InstallmentsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\Database\installments.sqlite&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Moreover I did following on startup in order to detect datadirecory:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);

        base.OnStartup(e);      
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting “The process cannot access” a local data file, you are probably opening it yourself and not closing it.

ClickOnce defines `|DataDirectory|` as the installer data folder. If your connection string is `|DataDirectory|\Database\installments.sqlite` then you need to mark your project's `Database` folder, not the `installments.sqlite` file, as the data file. Or you could change your connection string to`|DataDirectory|\installments.sqlite`

`SetData` does not “detect” DataDirectory, it replaces it. Do not call `SetData` as that will replace ClickOnce's value. If you need to know the installer target data folder you can call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")`, but if you are using ADO.NET you do not even need to do that; ADO.NET will replace `|DataDirectory|` in connection strings with the path to the installer data folder.

You probably just need to remove your `OnStartup` method; that's what is wrecking things.

Comment: i am using entity framework. I removed code from OnStartup function. I removed Database folder moved installments.sqlite outside it, changed connection string but publish still does not copy that file

Comment: I suspect something, most likely your own code, is opening installments.sqlite and not closing it. Finding that thing will probably require physical access to your development machine. [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) may help you in this.

Comment: sorry, it occured that when I additionally chandged build action to content then it succed along with your advise - thanks